# How to read from Multi-Dimensional dictionary C#

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, object

I am trying to figure out a better way to handle this object/dictionary puzzle that I have going on here.

Basically, I am getting a JSON iResponse (rest sharp) and deserializing into a Dictionary.  That works fine, but I get a massive dictionary that also contains objects and possibly more dictionarys?  I am a little confused.

Here is my code that grabs the response to put into a dictionary:

```
var TicketInfo = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<dynamic, dynamic>>(ticketExistsJSON.Content);
```

This is what I am getting in console:

[image: This is inside of my JiraTicketInfo]

So this is inside my JiraTicketInfo variable.  You can see its full of key value pairs, but inside the value of those key value pairs is another dictionary? In this dictionary contains the key value pairs I want.  I specifically only want number 1.

I found a way to finally get it with

> Dictionary JiraTicketInfo = TicketInfo["issues"][0]["fields"];
>
> var bumStatus = (object[])JiraTicketInfo["customfield_10004"];
>
> var numStatusDict = (Dictionary)bumStatus[0];
>
> JiraOrg = numStatusDict["name"].ToString();

But I feel like there is a much simpler way to obtain this, but my brain cant seem to understand the multi-dimensional dictionary

Any help would be much appreciated!

I am not even looking for an answer, just a place where to find one.  Thank you :)

here is my JSON response:

`{
  "expand": "names,schema",
  "startAt": 0,
  "maxResults": 1,
  "total": 1,
  "issues": [
    {
      "expand": "customfield_10087.properties,operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
      "id": "18293",
      "self": "https://www.myjirahost.com/rest/api/2/issue/18293",
      "key": "SS-2991",
      "fields": {
        "customfield_10070": null,
        "customfield_10071": null,
        "customfield_10072": null,
        "customfield_10073": null,
        "customfield_10074": null,
        "customfield_10075": null,
        "customfield_10089": null,
        "customfield_10004": [
          {
            "id": "99",
            "name": "Organization Name B",
            "_links": {
              "self": "https://www.myjirahost.com/rest/servicedeskapi/organization/99"
            }
          }
        ],
        "environment": null,
        "duedate": null
      }
    }
  ]
}`

Comment: Show us your JSON, probably there is a better structure possible than `Dictionary<dynamic, dynamic>` which is very vague

Comment: JIRA almost certainly returns a consistent JSON format meaning you should be deserialising into proper C# classes.

Comment: `Dictionary<dynamic, dynamic>` woah, i haven't even had my morning coffee. Basically 99.9999% of the time just seeing the word `dynamic` tells me there is something wrong or a better way

Comment: @TheGeneral - Yes, using `dynamic` is like going in to a Star Trek Holodeck and asking the Computer to turn off all safety protocols.

Comment: This link might help: http://json2csharp.com.

Comment: I just updated the question with my JSON response from my POST.  And I totally agree with you guys in regards to the dict dynamic,dynamic I just couldn't find a better way.

Thanks again for any help

Comment: Thank you Enigmativity, using classes I was able to do:

>RootObject JiraIssueObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(ticketExistsJSON.Content);

Which solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

Solved with help from you all using resttosharp website and building out classes:

> RootObject JiraIssueObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(ticketExistsJSON.Content);